# EFCore 5.0 DeleteBehavior.Cascade multiple cascade paths

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I have a 3 table Company, CompanyCertificates and FileRepo. They are in a relationship like that :

Company - To - CompanyCertificates (One - To - Many)

```
builder.HasOne(cc => cc.Company)
  .WithMany(cc => cc.CompanyCertificates)
  .HasForeignKey(cc=>cc.CompanyID)
  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

CompanyCertificates - To - FileRepo (One -To -One)

```
builder.HasOne<CompanyCertificate>(x => x.CompanyCertificate)
  .WithOne(x => x.FileRepo)
  .HasForeignKey<FileRepo>(x => x.CertificateID)
  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

when i delete a company, i wanna all related data to be erased,thats why i select their `DeleteBehavior` to `Cascade`.

When i try to delete a company, im getting a error and its says :
`Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_FileRepo_CompanyCertificate_CertificateID' on table 'FileRepo' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.`

i dont know how to fix that error,because i really want to erase all datas about that company. The real reasion is im holding high-quality images on that `FileRepo` table.

**Thanks for any suggestion!!!**

Comment: There is no cycle in these 3 tables. Most likely you have other tables in relation with 2 of these which are causing the cycle - note that the cycle is reported at the first place detected, which doesn't mean the problem (and resolution) is exactly there. For instance, do you have something like `User` table with `CreatedBy` FK to that table in tables in question?

Comment: yeah i have that ```User``` table and there is a relation like that : Company -To- User(One-ToMany)  and there is a ```Product``` table which is related to ````Company``` . That ```Product``` table has also in a relation with a ```FileRepo``` table but i didnt want to give in that answer. i was thinking like if i solve that,i can solve another one.